# JOIN is returning Multiple results when only One record matches the WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT images.filename, slugs.name FROM images, slugs
WHERE images.status = 1 AND slugs.name = 'test'
```

However, I only have 1 record where `slugs.name = 'test'` is true!

What is going on?

Comment: What are the results that you get back?

Comment: All rows with images.status = 1.

Comment: How many images.status = 1 do you have? You have nothing distinctly joining the two tables.

Comment: As a future note: **avoid the use of `FROM x, y`**, as it is the same as `FROM x CROSS JOIN y` :-) (There are some silly SQL syntax constructs, that being one of them: it saves a few character for a rather uncommon operation.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Others are pointing out what you have wrong (that you're getting a cartesian join), but not how to fix it. We need to know how rows in `images` are related to rows in `slugs`. If, say, there's a column called `BingoID` in both, that should match, then something like:

```
SELECT images.filename, slugs.name FROM images, slugs
WHERE images.status = 1 AND slugs.name = 'test' AND images.BingoID = slugs.BingoID
```

or,

```
SELECT images.filename, slugs.name
FROM images inner join slugs
   ON images.BingoID = slugs.BingoID
WHERE images.status = 1 AND slugs.name = 'test'
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplification :)

Answer (score 2):

but you probably have two images.status = 1.
They way you wrote it, it is almost a full join, a Cartesian multiplication.

Comment: Yes, slugs.name = 'test' has no effect! This is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

How are the images and slugs tables related?  I think you need to add an inner join, as the query you have will return as many slugs with the name "test" as entries in the images table.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have more than one `images.status = 1` :)

Your query match all rows from table `images` having `status = 1` with all rows from table `slugs` having `name = 'test'`.

Comment: it has effect. Try to eliminate it. You should put another condition that relate images and slugs.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance it's doing an implicit natural join because you're selecting from two tables like that.

Answer (score 1):

It makes a cross join and images table would have more than one rows then a new table is created having rows multiplication of no. of rows of both tables due to which this query giving more than one results.

You should try  right outer join to get single result try this

```
SELECT images.filename, slugs.name FROM images right outer join slugs
   on images.ID = slugs.ID
where images.status = 1 AND slugs.name = 'test'
```